# Why is the present continuous possible here? (run)

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I have the following exercise in my textbook:

> I can’t complain. I (**run**) my own consultancy business.

The context is “. . . conversation between two ex-colleagues who have not seen each other for some time.” It is asked to use the appropriate tense of **run**, one of the present simple and present continuous or both.

Both tenses are valid, according to the text book. Why is the present continuous valid?

Here, I think “run” is a dynamic verb. It is used to describe an ongoing action. Why, then, the present continuous? The activity of “running . . . business” hasn’t started at the time of speaking. The speaker doesn’t seem to suggest it is or may be temporary.

Comment: This [British Council site](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/present-continuous) may be useful.

Comment: It says “we are using the present continuous to talk about activities *at the moment of speaking* . . .” This is a very general description. I’d like to know why exactly is the present continuous appropriate in my example.

Comment: you can also use the present continuous if running your own company is a temporary thing or a new thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't complain.  I run my own consultancy business, I have no health problems, I enjoy my life, I … .

You make a statement, and then list reasons to justify why it should be that way.

> I can't complain.  I'm running my own consultancy business, I'm healthy, I'm enjoying my life, I … .

You make a statement, and then describe your self.

---

The first one is more objective and distant.
It describes *your life*, as it would appear to *other people* observing it.
It perhaps leaves room for doubting the opening statement.
One almost expects "But somehow … ." to follow.

The second one is more immediate and personal.
It describes *you* as *you* are experiencing life right now.
You are obviously happy with yourself.
It gives an impression of sincerity and honesty.
One almost expects "I'm so thankful … ." to follow.